# Octave GUI Command Window - can I increase the number of rows and columns displayed?

Tags: octave

I'm using the Octave GUI 5.0.2 on Windows 10.  Text is only displayed in the upper left portion of the window.  Under the current screen resolution 25 lines are displayed, with a width of 24 characters. I have enough space to display 50 lines of text at 75 characters per line.  So the last command is always displayed in the middle of the screen.  Additionally I can scroll to the left to see hidden text, but makes reading difficult, e.g. 'help' output has to be continually scrolled left and right.
My question - is there a command to set the number of rows and/or columns displayed in the Octave GUI?

[image: Octave GUI Command Window - only 25 lines are visible]

Comment: Same problem here since today (worked fine yesterday!). 22 lines, I get 74 characters.  Octave was the last thing running (fine) last night, first thing open this morning (error).
I have tried reboots, reinstalls and uninstalled and disabling Windows subsystem for Linux (which I have also had running for months).  No good.
Did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  I had changed the command window **font** to Lucida Console. Changed it (back) to Consola or Courier and instantly fully working again.

Comment: works like a charm. octave 7.1.0

Comment: Changing the font will at least change the behavior, I got a few more lines, but it is still not using the full window size. It seem to depend more on the font size than the font type. So I would still want to know if you can set the console width and height in number of characters.

Comment: I tried several fonts and the portion of the window that it was using stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to screen resolution on multi-display systems. Can't find a fix, but resizing the workspace to approx half of my 1920*1080 makes it usable for me.